# Let C[0,1] be the space of continous functions in R. Show that Norm 1 its a norm on C[0,1]

Tags: calculus, topological-vector-spaces

norm p was defined as such:

$|.|_p=(\int_0^1|f(x)|^p dx)^{1/p}$

so, the norm 1 should look like this:

$|.|_1=(\int_0^1|f(x)| dx)$

when proving homogeneity and triangle inequality i just used the integral properties of constant multiple and sum of integrals; respectively. Now, my problem its with positive definiteness. my guess is this: since every function you are going to pluck its continous over a close interval, then its riemann integrable. If you're going to take the absolute value of *that* function, its always gonna be positive, then the result of the integral its always positive since the result of the integral of a positive riemann integrable function its always positive. I am doubtful about the last bit.

is this alright? Is there something i am missing?

thanks, any hint will help.

Answer (score 0):

*Continuity* matters. The only continuous nonnegative function with integral equal to zero on $[0,1]$ is the zero function. For continuous $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$, $\int_0^1|f|=0\iff\|f\|_1=0\iff f\equiv0$.

This is well known and is proved many times on this site.

> The result of the integral of a positive Riemann integrable function its always positive

Well, $f:x\mapsto\begin{cases}1&x=0\\0&0<x\le1\end{cases}$ is Riemann integrable, and not identically zero, yet $\int f=0$. So I'm not quite sure what you're getting at here: *continuity* is important. Either you do that, *or* as in the $\mathscr{L}^p$-space theory, we identify functions that are almost everywhere equal to get around this issue.